# find Fourier transform on this given function the function is: $f(x)=e^{-\alpha x^2} , \alpha > 0$

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-differential-equations

im working on a PDE question.

which states :  find Fourier transform on this given function
the function is:
$$f(x)=e^{-\alpha x^2} , \alpha > 0$$

we know that for Fourier transform :
$$F(w)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-iwx} dx$$

so
$$F(w)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\alpha x^2} e^{-iwx} dx$$

how should I solve this ?

I tried to simplify it but it just got more complicated.

Comment: Hint: calculate $F'(\omega)$ and try to write it in terms of $F(\omega)$.

Comment: @Bobo doesnt this make it more complicated than simplify it ?